# Не получается обезвредить вирус в непонятном месте

Tags: windows, kaspersky

Вобщем касперский нашел вирусы в папке корзины в которой лежат какие то непонятные  папки. (?какие то данные пользователей?)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При попытке удалить просто не удаляет, часа 2 стоял так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться

Comment: не по тематике сайта. Вопрос нужно закрыть

Comment: Грузишь любой livecd и грохаешь папки оттуда.